# SDL2 executable not working outside CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, sdl-2, game-development

I recently developed a SDL2 game using C++ and the latest version of CodeBlocks. The game works just fine if I run it inside the IDE - the problem is that if I try to run it outside CodeBlocks it will get an error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)
```

What should I do in order to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ship/install *all* libraries that your application uses. This includes SDL, but also your compilers runtime libraries.

If you don't include *all* libraries your application links with, then it cannot run.
And no, just linking with them locally is not enough. You need to ship them to the other computer that needs to run the program.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I linked SDL2 from CodeBlocks using LazyFoo's tutorial. If I intend to wrap my project in order for someone to play the game, should I add in the folder of the project more files excepting the .exe, the .dlls and the media folders?

Comment: @OnofreiTudor You need to put all `.dll`s (non-system ones) your program uses to the same directory as the `.exe`. To check if you got the right dlls, you can open the terminal (`cmd`), do `set PATH=`, and try running the program. It should complain about missing dlls (then you copy them from your compiler `bin` directory). When it stops complaining, you're done. For this to work properly, make sure the dlls present in your compiler bin directory were **not** copied to `C:\Windows`, `C:\Windows\System32`, `...\SysWow64` or `...\System`. They shouldn't be there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have already done that for the project itself and for the attempt to wrap the game.

Comment: @OnofreiTudor So you already copied the `.dll`s? Then you got the wrong ones.

Comment: I was reffering to the SDL2 .dlls. The project doesn't complain of missing .dlls.

Comment: @OnofreiTudor The answer is the same, you somehow got the wrong `SDL2.dll`. Maybe an 64-bit one, while your compiler is 32-bit, or vice versa. Also note that shipping `SDL2.dll` alone is not enough. Your program also depends on some dlls in your compiler `bin` directory; the only reason it doesn't complain about them is because that directory is in the `PATH`. Your users won't have those dlls, so you have to ship some of them with your exe.

Comment: There will also be dlls for the c++ runtime. if the compiler is not from Microsoft don't expect the dlls to be installed on a PC. Even if you use the Microsoft compiler you probably want to package the redistributable anyways in your installer you create for your application. I use NSIS but there are several other installers available.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The problem was primarily with the compiler that I was using. When I moved on to Visual Studio, all of them vanished. Changing the lib documents and the .dlls according to the target's system architecture creates a functional executable.